# How to ensure all htaccess rewrite rules work without fail

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my `htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(online-shop)/?$ $1/home [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(my-integra)/?$ $1/home [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(blog)/(post|tags)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&type=$2&unique=$3 [QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(blog)/(archives)/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})?$ index.php?id=$1&type=$2&year=$3&month=$4 [QSA,NC]
```

The two rules at the bottom do not seem to work, if i visit `domain.com/blog/post/post-1` it does not show the correct page and is just showing `index.php?id=blog/post/post1` rather than `index.php?id=blog&type=post&unique=post1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is being applied to very next `RewriteRule` only. Also keep generic rule as last rule.

Have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(online-shop)/?$ $1/home [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(my-integra)/?$ $1/home [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(blog)/(post|tags)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&type=$2&unique=$3 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(blog)/(archives)/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})?$ index.php?id=$1&type=$2&year=$3&month=$4 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```